# What does this command means - "nohup ./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 &"?

Tags: java, linux, jboss, jboss7.x

I have a heavy application running on **jboss-7.1.1** on **linux** server. I came across this command to start the jboss "**nohup ./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 &**".
But i want to understand more about this command line. Also the **nohup.out** file size keeps on increasing day by day. Is it due to the command line that i executed to start the jboss. Is there any way to **avoid** nohup.out to get created.

Comment: maybe use disown rather than nohup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### nohup

`nohup` makes the following command immune to the SIGHUP signal. It detaches the command from the terminal. When a terminal is closed, any process (or commands) running in the terminal are sent the SIGHUP (hang-up) signal and then die.

This means that if the terminal screen is closed (the terminal from where ./standalone.sh is started), `standalone.sh` remains running. It is detached from it's terminal.

### Foreground and background

The `&` at the end of the command puts the `standalone.sh` program in the **background**. Background means that the command does not block the terminal shell. A command in the foreground on the other hand will block any input to the terminal shell until it has completed.

An example: `read -p "enter name "` expects input from the user. It blocks the terminal shell until ENTER is keyed. The `read` command is in the **foreground** and blocks the terminal from receiving further commands.  A background process does not block the shell that started it.

### **nohup.out**

This file contains the output from the command issued using `nohup`. In your case it is the output from the standalone.sh script.

You can direct the output from a command to a file:

```
nohup ./standalone.sh -b 0 0 0 0 & > myfile.txt
```

Or even dispose of the output by writing to `/dev/null`. If you do this you will lose any errors generated by the command.

```
  nohup ./standalone.sh -b 0 0 0 0 & > /dev/null
```

If you want to preserve any error messages, but want to ignore any other output, then redirect the error stream (stream 2) thus:

```
 nohup ./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 & >/dev/null 2>my-error-file.txt"
```

Comment: This is what i was actually looking for. Thank you very much for the info. 
Appreciate your prompt response. Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add to great suspectus's answer:

```
./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```

**./standalone.sh** start **jboss-7.1.1** in standalone mode (war files located in *JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments* using *JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration* configs and so on) on all available networks.

**-b** sets system property *jboss.bind.address* and **0.0.0.0** means on all network interfaces. Like *127.0.0.1*, your external IP address, your IP in your local network and so on. So, your jboss will be available on all network interfaces you are currently connected.